# Unable to render Grid View

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have grid view in my user control, and I am getting below error:

```
RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();
```

I am using `gv.RenderControl(htw);`

My code is as below:

```
private void ExportToExcel(string strFileName, GridView gv)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

And to avoid Server control was created outside form control exception I am using below code:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```

But I'm using all this code in a usercontrol, There isn't this method in the base class.
What should I do, even I placed above in my page in which I place my user control, but still I am getting above error

Also note I am using masterpage in which I have form tagged already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting EnableEventValidation in page directive  to false solved my problem.

```
 <%@ Page ............ EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
Page pg = new Page();
HtmlForm hf = new HtmlForm();

hf.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
hf.Controls.Add(gv);

pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
pg.Controls.Add(hf);
pg.DesignerInitialize();
pg.RenderControl(hw);

Current.Response.Clear();
Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
Current.Response.Charset = string.Empty;
Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Current.Response.End();
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim sw As New StringWriter
Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
Dim pg As New Page()
Dim hf As New HtmlForm()

hf.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
hf.Controls.Add(gv)

pg.EnableEventValidation = False
pg.Controls.Add(hf)
pg.DesignerInitialize()
pg.RenderControl(hw)

Current.Response.Clear()
Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls")
Current.Response.Charset = String.Empty
Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString())
Current.Response.End()
```

Comment: I need help regarding C#, not vb.net @nikita

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody, Edited, sorry. Also, good tool: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render(); this errror I am getting now  @nikita